# What is the difference between STOP and ERROR STOP?

Tags: fortran

Fortran has `stop` and `error stop`, both of which exit the program prematurely and can return an error code.

**What is the difference between the two, and when should either be used?** (Also, are there implementation/compiler concerns here?)

I understand from [Intel's documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679946) that `stop` terminates the program, whereas `error stop` appears to do a little more. That page is useful but does not entirely answer my question, because 1) it's a little too technical for me, and 2) I know that the Fortran standard(s) leave room for "artistic expression" among implementations, so I don't trust that page to perfectly reflect the standard.

I note that this question is related to [What is the difference between "stop" and "exit" in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475725/what-is-the-difference-between-stop-and-exit-in-fortran) — in fact, my question was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34476302/1180930) to that question. Whereas that question asks the difference between `stop` and `exit`, I'm specifically looking at the nitty-gritty differences between `stop` and `error stop`. My question here would have been a useful addition to that question in retrospect, but since it wasn't, this is a separate question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fortran has two types of termination of execution: *normal* termination and *error* termination.

Normal termination commences when a `stop` statement or an `end program` statement is reached.  Error termination comes about with an `error stop` statement or other forms of errors (such as with in input/output, allocation, or other such forms).

So, in the simplest manner a `stop` statement initiates normal termination and an `error stop` statement initiates error termination.

As noted, there is indeed more to "termination".

For normal termination (whether through a `stop` or not) there are three phases: initiation, synchronization, and completion.  In a single-image (non-coarray) program these things flow from one to the other.  With more than one image, images synchronize after initiation until all have commenced normal termination.  After synchronization the termination process undergoes completion.  There is no "cascading" of normal termination.

For error termination, once one image initiates this all other images which haven't already started terminating undergo (error) termination "as quickly as possible".  That is, the entire program comes to a crashing halt once one image kicks it off.

These aspects are not "processor-dependent", to the extent that if a compiler is a Fortran compiler it follows these things.  However, not all (versions of all) compilers are full Fortran compilers of the current standard.  In particular, some compilers do not support `error stop`.  The distinction of the two forms is less important without coarray implementation.

There is (at least) one aspect where compilers are allowed to vary in detail.  If no integer stop code is given, on `stop` the standard recommends a zero value be passed as the exit code of the process (where such a concept is supported).  If no integer stop code is given on `error stop`, then Fortran 2018 recommends a non-zero value be passed as the exit code.

From the Intel documentation linked, ifort follows this first recommendation.

Finally, a `stop` statement is an *image control statement*; an `error stop` statement is not. Image control statements affect ordering of images, and are restricted in where they appear. For example, `stop` statements may not appear in a pure subprogram<sup>1</sup> or in a `do concurrent` block.

---

<sup>1</sup> Whatever one thinks of the use of `stop` and `error stop` inside functions, it's fair to say that `stop` in particular should generally be avoided completely inside functions.

Comment: This is a great explanation!

Comment: Thanks - to be honest I nearly didn't bother posting it after reading your answer which covers most of these things.  Still, it doens't hurt to say the same thing in multiple ways.

Comment: Good answers both of you, I had no time to consult references so these more accurate answers with details were needed.

Answer (score 7):

`Error stop` is (obviously?) meant to be used in case of error termination  of the program while `stop` is used terminate the program even in normal circumstances. Some even used to write `stop` before each `end`.

`error stop` was introduced in Fortran 2008 together with coarrays and is useful for stopping all running images (processes) while `stop` just stops execution of the current image.

`stop` cannot be used in `pure` procedures while `error stop` can (new feature of Fortran 2018).

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Vladimir F's great answer, the statement

```
error stop [ stop-code ]  ! stop-code is an integer or default character constant expression and has the same meaning as for the stop statement.
```

has more severe consequences in parallel programs than a simple `stop`. When executed on one coarray image (processor, thread,...), it initiates error termination there and hence causes all other images that have not already initiated error termination to initiate error termination. It causes the whole calculation to stop as soon as is possible. Therefore, `error stop` should be used in parallel programming when a severe error in one of the images makes the entire simulation useless for the rest of images.

To the contrary, a single `stop` statement stops only those images that have reached it, as far as I am aware and used it in Coarray Fortran. Other images can check the status of a specific image or images that have failed (stopped) using

```
sync images([image numbers],stat=syncstat)
if (syncstat==stat_stopped_image) then
   ! do something appropriate
end if
```

The flag `stat_stopped_image` is a constant that is available from `iso_fortran_env` intrinsic module in Fortran 2008 onward.